# How to detect what is preventing multiple cores being used in golang?

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

So, I have a piece of code that is concurrent and it's meant to be run onto each CPU/core.

There are two large vectors with input/output values

```
var (
    input = make([]float64, rowCount)
    output = make([]float64, rowCount)
)
```

these are filled and I want to compute the distance (error) between each input-output pair. Being the pairs independent, a possible concurrent version is the following:

```
var d float64 // Error to be computed
// Setup a worker "for each CPU"
ch := make(chan float64)
nw := runtime.NumCPU()
for w := 0; w < nw; w++ {
    go func(id int) {
         var wd float64
         // eg nw = 4
         // worker0, i = 0, 4, 8, 12...
         // worker1, i = 1, 5, 9, 13...
         // worker2, i = 2, 6, 10, 14...
         // worker3, i = 3, 7, 11, 15...
         for i := id; i < rowCount; i += nw {
             res := compute(input[i])
             wd += distance(res, output[i])
         }
         ch <- wd
    }(w)
}
// Compute total distance
for w := 0; w < nw; w++ {
    d += <-ch
}
```

The idea is to have a single worker for each CPU/core, and each worker processes a subset of the rows.

The problem I'm having is that this code is no faster than the serial code.

Now, I'm using Go 1.7 so `runtime.GOMAXPROCS` should be already set to `runtime.NumCPU()`, but even setting it explicitly does not improves performances.

- distance is just `(a-b)*(a-b)`;
- compute is a bit more complex, but should be reentrant and use global data **only for reading** (and uses `math.Pow` and `math.Sqrt` functions);
- no other goroutine is running.

So, besides accessing the global data (input/output) for reading, there are no locks/mutexes that I am aware of (not using `math/rand`, for example).

I also compiled with `-race` and nothing emerged.

My host has 4 virtual cores, but when I run this code I get (using htop) CPU usage to 102%, but I expected something around 380%, as it happened in the past with other go code that used all the cores.

I would like to investigate, but I don't know how the runtime allocates threads and schedule goroutines.

How can I debug this kind of issues? Can `pprof` help me in this case? What about the `runtime` package?

Thanks in advance

Comment: actually you have one hidden mutex behind `ch` channel

Comment: Yes, thanks! But the mutex is used only `nw` times, which is usually a low number when compared to the data to be processed, and the channel is used very late in the whole computation process. I don't know if that is the issue, but even if it was, my question remains: how do I know that it is because of that mutex that my code is not using more CPUs?

Comment: You are right. I just tried a sample similar to yours and it uses all available cores. I think full code example will be more useful.

Comment: Speaking of locks, you can use go test -mutexprofile flag in order to profile lock contentions.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting! But apparently it's a 1.8 feature, I'm using 1.7 right now. I guess that I'll try that if I cannot come up with a better solution.

Comment: `pprof` still had a blocking profile which shows time spent blocking on synchronization primitives in general. If you're creating too much garbage, it's possible you're limited by the garbage collector. You can see the GC activity using `GODEBUG=gctrace=1`, but I suggest you start by reading up on profiling Go programs.

Comment: @JimB thanks. I'll give pprof an in-depth look because I didn't know about this feature and I used cpu profiling only to check how much time was used by each routine. I don't think it's a GC issue, as the code pre-allocates most of the memory it uses, but I'll give it a check anyway. Thanks again EDIT btw, I tried GOGC=off and no performance improvement. Also, GC didn't show up in pprof top10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but in the end I got the measurement wrong. @JimB was right, and I had a minor leak, but not so much to justify a slowdown of this magnitude.

My expectations were too high: the function I was making concurrent was called only at the beginning of the program, therefore the performance improvement was just minor.

After applying the pattern to other sections of the program, I got the expected results. My mistake in evaluation which section was the most important.

Anyway, I learned a lot of interesting things meanwhile, so thanks a lot to all the people trying to help!